# Lazy Load для opencart

Tags: opencart, lazyloading

Подскажите как правильно подключить Lazy Load для opencart, что и в какие файлы необходимо прописать. Я не особо разбираюсь в opencart, может кто уже устанавливал подобное?

Answer (score 1):

Подгружать скрипт следует в контроллере той страницы, где хотите использовать плагин. Например, вы хотите Lazy Load на картинках в каталоге товаров. В этом случае в контроллере каталога `catalog/controller/product/category.php` необходимо прописать следующее (где-нибудь, до рендера представления `$this->response->setOutput(...` ):

```
$this->document->addStyle('путь/к/файлу/стилей/стиль.css'); // для .css
$this->document->addScript('путь/к/файлу/скрипта/скрипт.js'); // для .js
```

Если нет желания заморачиваться, можете выводить подключаемые файлы для всего сайта. Для этого проделайте всё выше описанное, но в файле контроллера футера `catalog/controller/common/footer.php` или хедера `catalog/controller/common/header.php`

Answer (score 0):

Выше все верно расписали, но хотелось бы дополнить - есть еще такая вещь упрощающая эти действия, может пригодится https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/